# Iterating over a time series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set indexed by time (time series). I have to calculate, for each day, the average of my variable every 5 data this is my code :

```
dftec=dftec.groupby([dftec["Datetime"].dt.day])

for key, item in dftec:
    df = dftec.get_group(key)
    print(df)
```

It works i have df for each day
But when i try to iterate like this :

```
for key, item in dftec:
d=[]
df = dftec.get_group(key)
print(df)
for i in range(1, df.shape[0], 5):
    d.append(df['debitVD'].iloc[i:i + 5, :].mean())
    print(d)
```

I've got the following error : pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers (on the line d.append)

Comment: Please add a tag for the programming language used

Comment: Hi yes, it's python

Comment: `df['debitVD']` is a series (1-dimension). Try `df['debitVD'].iloc[i:i + 5].mean()` instead